# iText pdf generation fails on Android browsers

Tags: java, android, spring, pdf, itext

I'm getting some weird behavior on Android devices with an application using iText. It's a typical Java/Spring web app, nothing fancy, and it uses iText to generate some simple pdf's (nothing major, ~50k in file size).

It's just the standard `response.setContentType("application/pdf");`, and it works fine in every desktop browser I've tried, and it works on iOS, but it fails on every Android device I've tested it on. Well, mostly fails...

On Samsung Galaxy devices, my own Note 4 (running Android 5.0.1) and one of the 10" tablets, on both the stock browser and Chrome, it fails to download at all - it tosses a notification "*controllerName*.bin failed to download", where the actual name of the pdf is replaced by the name of the controller fired to generate it.

It will actually download on an HTC One M9 (running Android 5.1) on both the stock browser and Chrome, but it still replaces the pdf name with the controller name and downloads it as a .bin rather than a pdf. Renaming the file to a pdf opens it perfectly though. It also downloads this way on Firefox for Android on the Galaxy devices.

Windows and Apple devices have no trouble, it's only doing this on Android. I'm trying to find any consistent method that would work across most devices, I'm just out of my depth on the Android side of things. Any pointers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you throw some extra headers to the HTTP response. See the [PdfServlet](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=173) example. Do you provide the content length? Some browsers don't like it if you don't tell them in advance how many bytes you'll be sending them. Obviously this isn't an iText problem (it works on almost all the browsers you've tested). It's a problem on the client-side. Google doesn't seem to like PDFs (shame on them).

Comment: Good suggestion, thank you, I'll try that out. I figured it had to be something client-side, I'm just a little adrift in the sea of variety that Android offers.  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've sorted this out, following @Bruno's [PdfServlet](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=173) example (and thank you again!).

The original developer on this thing invoked the PdfWriter like so,

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
```

It seems that `response.getOutputStream()` is the culprit, causing that weird behavior on Android.

As in the example code, I changed it to use ByteArrayOutputStream:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
```

Then write the output back to the servlet output stream:

```
// write ByteArrayOutputStream to the ServletOutputStream
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(os);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

And just like that, consistent behavior across Android devices.

Comment: can you provide a full version of the code? @ZachJohnson

Comment: @Shivam, I'm sorry, I don't have access to the project that was for anymore. I think it pretty much followed the basic iText examples though...